# "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again." is going on for several days and won't go away

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, spreadsheet, server-error

i have a spreadsheet with a list of songs that i've selected to ease the boredom of my pupils at school. so i've written this code to publish 3 songs from this list every day at 9:00 AM on my course on classroom and it worked fine for some days, then it started to report the error that you see in the title.

the code is the following

```
function createTrigger() { 
  // Trigger every day at 9
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('pubblicavideo')
      .timeBased()
      .atHour(9)
      .everyDays(1) // Frequency is required if you are using atHour() or nearMinute()
      .create();
}

function onOpen() { 
  //aggiunge il bottone autotrigger con run e stop all'apertura del documento spreadsheet
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  ui.createMenu("Auto Trigger")
    .addItem("Run","runAuto")
    .addItem("Stop","deleteTrigger")
    .addToUi();
}

function runAuto() { 

  // resets the loop counter if it's not 0
  refreshUserProps(); 
   // clear out the sheet
  clearData();  
  // create trigger to run program automatically
  createTrigger();
}

function refreshUserProps() {
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  userProperties.setProperty('loopCounter', 0);
  userProperties.setProperty('contarighe', 1);
}



function deleteTrigger() {

  // Loop over all triggers and delete them
  var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
  }
}

function pubblica(k)
{
  var corso = Classroom.Courses.get(61109944129);
  var foglio = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var linkini = foglio.getRange("C2:C2014");
  var titolini = foglio.getRange("B2:B2014");
  var autorini = foglio.getRange("A2:A2014");
  var cell = linkini.getCell(k, 1);
  var cella = titolini.getCell(k, 1);
  var cello = autorini.getCell(k, 1);
  var link = cell.getValue();
  var titolo = cella.getValue();
  var autore = cello.getValue();
  var courseWork = {
  'title': titolo,
  'description': autore,
  'materials': [
     {'link': { 'url': link }}    
],
  'workType': 'ASSIGNMENT',
  'state': 'PUBLISHED',
}
Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create(courseWork, 61109944129);
}

function clearData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');

  // clear out the matches and output sheets
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  if (lastRow > 1) {
    sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow-1,1).clearContent();
  }
}



function pubblicavideo()
{
  var pezzialgiorno = 3;   //numero di pezzi da pubblicare ogni giorno
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');


   var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var loopCounter = Number(userProperties.getProperty('loopCounter'));
  var contarighe = Number(userProperties.getProperty('contarighe'));
  // put some limit on the number of loops
  // could be based on a calculation or user input
  // using a static number in this example
  var limit = 671;

  // if loop counter < limit number, run the repeatable action
  if (loopCounter < limit) {

    // see what the counter value is at the start of the loop
    Logger.log(loopCounter);

    // do stuff
   for (var i=0; i<pezzialgiorno; i++)
   {
     pubblica(contarighe);
     contarighe++;
   }
     // increment the properties service counter for the loop
    loopCounter +=1;
    userProperties.setProperty('loopCounter', loopCounter);
    userProperties.setProperty('contarighe', contarighe);

    // see what the counter value is at the end of the loop
    Logger.log(loopCounter);
    Logger.log(contarighe);
  }

  // if the loop counter is no longer smaller than the limit number
  // run this finishing code instead of the repeatable action block
  else {

    // Log message to confirm loop is finished
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1).setValue("Finished");
    Logger.log("Finished");

     // delete trigger because we've reached the end of the loop
    // this will end the program
    deleteTrigger();  
  }
}
```

i tried to modify the code but it prevents me from saving it because of the same error. i've tried to look at the executions report and i found this

report of failed executions. you can see (i hope) that it worked until april the 3rd and then nothing worked anymore, not even the onOpen part, always the same error[image]

so i can't change the code, i can't run it, i can't stop it, and it doesn't work. what should i do?

Comment: Contact whoever runs that site you're interacting with

Comment: There's nothing here we can help you with. Your code uses some API that is running somewhere else (probably server-side), so you'll need to be able to troubleshoot the server.

Comment: Remove the trigger. Make a copy of your sheet and set up the script in the new sheet.

Comment: I've edited the tags  For future reference, using the right tag lets your question reach the right audience.

Comment: the interactions are only between google spreadsheet and google classroom, and the script is not working even with the function onOpen that should been interacting just between the script and the spreadsheet. i tried copying the spreadsheet and the script, for now it seem to be working. what should i do in case it stops again? (other than copying again, of course)

Comment: Give feedback to Google. create a issue in issuetracker. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.